# Jquery: Can't toggle between Jquery UI sortable and owl carousel dynamically

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, owl-carousel

I'm trying to toggle between owl carousel and jquery UI sortable(grid type) for the following div.
the problem occurs when trying to toggle from carousel to sortable mode.

```
<div  class="grid">
    <div id="i_1">A</div>
    <div id="i_2">B</div>
    <div id="i_3">C</div>
    <div id="i_4">D</div>           
</div>

<div><button  id="enable-owl">owl</button></div>
<div><button  id="enable-sortable">sortable</button></div>
```

the javascript:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

 $(".grid").sortable({
            tolerance: 'pointer',
            revert: 400,
            placeholder: 'placeholder tile',
            forceHelperSize: true,            
      });
 $( "#enable-owl" ).button().on( "click", function() {

                  $( ".grid" ).sortable( "disable" );
                 $(".grid").toggleClass("dyna-owl");
                   $(".dyna-owl").owlCarousel();
                });
 $( "#enable-sortable" ).button().on( "click", function(){           

                  $( ".grid" ).sortable( "enable" );
                 $(".grid").toggleClass("dyna-owl");                     

                });


});
```

jsfiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/jackhammer94/w6vhu163/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want them to work properly you need to *distroy* them not just *disable* them, because the styles and extra elements that are created interfere with the functionality of the other plugin.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var sort_options = {                        // save this for later use
        tolerance: 'pointer',
        revert: 400,
        placeholder: 'placeholder tile',
        forceHelperSize: true,
    };

    $(".grid").sortable(sort_options);         // use the options 

    $("#enable-owl").button().on("click", function () {

        $(".grid").sortable("destroy");       // destroy sortable
        $(".grid").toggleClass("dyna-owl");
        $(".dyna-owl").owlCarousel();         // enable owlCarousel

    });


    $("#enable-sortable").button().on("click", function () {

        $('.dyna-owl').data('owlCarousel').destroy();    // destroy owlCarousel
        $(".grid").toggleClass("dyna-owl");
        $(".grid").sortable(sort_options);    // enable sortable with the options

    });

});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/w6vhu163/2/)